# Suppose $A$ is a set of $10$ natural numbers between $1$ and $100$. Show that two disjoint nonempty subsets of $A$ have the same sum.

Tags: combinatorics

> Suppose $A$ is a set of $10$ natural numbers between $1$ and $100$. Show that two disjoint nonempty subsets of $A$ have the same sum.

I don't see how this is true, for example if I take a set, $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$

Then the sets $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\{6,7,8,9,10\}$ clearly have different sums.

Unless I just have to show there exists one? In which case I have no idea how to do this.

My best guess is maybe I divide $100$ naturals into blocks of $10$ in order, so $\{1,...,10\},\{11,...,20\}$ etc. Then I clearly cant take 10 from any one set.  But Im not sure how to continue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104449/discussion-on-question-by-acoloredreptile-suppose-a-is-a-set-of-10-natural-n).